# Store html into variable on click, erase from the DOM and put it back in on another click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I'm trying to build an ON/OFF button for a video. What I'd like it to do is fairly simple: on the first click, it deletes the video (not stop it) and, on the second, it puts it back into the dom.

I've come up with a bit of code, but it doesn't work the way I want it to:

```
$('#on-off').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (videoContent !== ""){
        var videoContent = $('#video-container').html();
        console.log(videoContent);
            // At this point, the console shows the variable videoContent does contain the content of #video-container.
        $('#video-container').html("");
    }
    else {
        $('#video-container').html(videoContent);
    }
});
```

The first click works fine and stores the content of #video-container into videoContent.
The second doesn't put the content of videoContent back in #video-container, however. In fact, it erases the content of videoContent.

I'm sure this is something pretty simple to solve, I just can't figure it out.
Thanks

Comment: Does it work, if you move the variable 'videoContent' into global variable scope?

Comment: Try setting your `videoContent` as a global variable

Comment: why the downvotes guys, this seems like a genuine question to me

Answer (score 1):

Put the variable `videoContent` in the global scope:

```
var videoContent = '';

$('#on-off').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (videoContent !== ""){
        videoContent = $('#video-container').html();
        $('#video-container').html("");
    }
    else {
        $('#video-container').html(videoContent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. By doing that, the console log I call after videoContent = $('#video-container').html(); doesn't return anything, as variable remains empty.

Comment: it probably still isn't global because it is still inside a function?